# Failed to connect to port 10.0.2.2(port 80):ETIMEDOUT caused by ETIMEDOUT

Tags: android, network-programming

I am trying to build Android Login app with PHP,mySQL and localhost. However it displays connection problems. I tried both emulator and Android device. 
I also tried IP address of my WLAN by finding its IP from ifconfig under Wireless LAN Adapter Wifi 2. My Android device uses the same WIFIconnection(although I have a repeater too, if that info is of any use). It used to display 'ehostunreach' in my emulator. And 'ehostunreach' & 'etimedout' in my Android device.
I hope this much detail is enough. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/login.php";
    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
             ........
```

Comment: Did you tested "http://10.0.2.2/login.php" in Phone's browser? Does it open?

Comment: It doesn't. The ping of 10.0.2.2 on my PCwas unsuccessful, as pointed out by someone else, so I tried using my WLAN IP address. It's ping was successful, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

It is not able to reach that server. Try a ping to 10.0.2.2 from your PC and probably you will get timeout. First try to get a successful ping. Maybe the server doesn't have that IP address or your router is filtering out messages.

Comment: It times out. So I tried using my WLAN IP address i.e. 192.168.0.104. The ping is successful, but still doesn't work on my phone.

Comment: @ChiragMakhija, if you cannot access that IP from anywhere then it's not a problem in your smartphone or your program. Try to access a known site like google.com or stackoverflow.com and see if you get the same error. If you have the same error then you might have a problem in your router.

Comment: @ChiragMakhija please let me know how you were able to fix this issue?

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is a special ip address used by google Emulators to map to the hosts IPv4 address. YOU CAN NEVER PING IT from the pc.